# Which app will potentially not work with Mojave?

Tags: compatibility, mojave

Is there a way to find out which apps already installed on my Mac with High Sierra will potentially have problems with Mojave.

Before trying to figure out the sometimes hard to understand messages and errors occurring after Mojave install.

**Some examples of frustration finding it afterwards**...

[GarageBand stopped recognizing my piano/keyboard after installing MacOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/340351/46541)

or others not always pre-installed app or hardware related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mojave

Comment: How about you share a list of installed app (or just the app you think could possibly not run as they are no longer actively developed) and folks who have them installed share their feedback? The way it is put currently, the query is very broad and may not end up being helpful (for your case).

Comment: We stopped doing this kind of "list" questions a while ago as they didn't really work very well on the long run. Asking for apps which don't work with Mojave doesn't provide useful information on the long run, nobody will come back and update their answer in case an update makes the app run, and there are sites out there who take care of maintaining such lists.

Comment: @nohillside Just trying to spare the ppl the frustration of things not working after upgrade. This site is full of that kind of questions at the moment.

Comment: There are some (few) specific questions about issues with specific applications, which is fine. If you want to make a case for a more welcome handling of "list" type questions please raise it on the Meta site.

Comment: And the list above is actually a good example for why it doesn't really fit the site: There are at least three applications on the list for which Mojave-ready versions have been available since Monday or before.

Comment: @nohillside if not list, how do you suggest ppl find out before upgrading and having all the frustrations or is that not possible ?

Comment: I don't say the list doesn't have value (as long as it's correct), I just say it doesn't suite AD and the Q&A format used here very well, not even as a community wiki.

Comment: @nohillside now look at that, this question had more than 1,000 Views.

Comment: The problem with this question is you're asking to prove one condition by disproving all other negative conditions.  This is like asking for a list of all numbers that when added together *don't* equal 4. Instead, you need to verify that the software your interested in is Mojave compatible and move forward.

Comment: @Buscar웃 So? I never said that there isn’t an interest in such a list. But how big the interest may be it is not a good fit for the Q&A format on this site (for reasons outlined above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps that don't work at all as of Sep. 26 2018.

Since this situation changes hourly/daily, I will not be updating this list.

```
BetterTouchTool (see thread for update, working beta release at https://folivora.ai/blog/post/13005)
Box Drive (crashes when trying to open)
CleanMyMac 3 (they have a Mojave beta version ready, email their support on support@macpaw.com to get hands on it) (Version 3.10.0b1 appears to work and is available for download)
Cocktail
Evernote (-> Evernote 7.3 Beta 1 now works with Mojave)
Game Golf Transfer - starts when device is plugged in but then gets "USB CONNECTION LOST error
Hands Off! (3.2.7)
IBM Client Application Access
IBM Notes
iTunes 12.6.4 & 12.6.5 (if you try to install, you just get "This software is not supported on your system.")
iStat Pro (Cannot be installed)
LastPass (App does not work. Browser plugin barely works) (10.14 B2)
Little Snitch 4.1.2 (not compatible with Mojave)
Live Home 3D (3.3.4 build 874) by BeLight Software - app launches to Project Gallery but won't open any selection or new document
MacTracker 7.7.4 (main window loads, clicking on any device will cause app to freeze)
MailButler 2.1
Malwarebytes (3.3.22) (tries to update app, installer freezes, forces uninstall of app)
Mindjet Mindmanager 11 (Build 11.1.160- application crashes at start)
NFSManager, stops with a window unsupported OS version
OS X Fuse 3.80 (Will not install)
Paste 2 (crashes when copying something to the clipboard)
PIA v80 (loads, connects to VPN server but blocks all internet traffic - Mojave also throws "legacy" warning)
PowerPhotos (crashes on startup)
Sculptris
Sound Control
SQLPro Studio (launches, runs slow, then crashes and won’t reopen)
Unlox (launches and runs fine but cannot unlock via iOS counterpart, tap to unlock also broken - UPDATE: developer has released beta version with full Mojave functionality, can find info on Twitter @UnloxHelp)
VyprVPN
VMWare Horizon Client (Older version 4.1 works. Current version 4.7 does not)
VirtualBox
```

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked at my machine and I have only 3 of them; two are fairly obscure or obsolete but the third is Kindle from Amazon (admittedly, I almost never use the Kindle app on the mac, 99% of the time I read books on the iPad).

It's mind boggling that a company with as much resources cannot update their app, they will likely wait until the next update when they will be *forced* to do so :)

Comment: If Apple says "macOS Mojave *is* the last release *to support 32-bit*" then this list you propose is for 10.15, not Mojave.

Comment: The transition could still take a while. Also from, https://support.apple.com/HT208436 When will the 64-bit transition be complete?
 The 64-bit transition for macOS and macOS apps is still underway, so final transition dates have not yet been established. But now is a good time to check with the software developer to see if 64-bit versions of your favorite titles are available.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb:

Big applications, professional applications, essential applications and audio applications will not work immediately correctly.

This is just Murphy's law.

Therefore you should wait a bit in principle.

Audio application developers now routinely issue warnings on new macOS releases.

There is no perfect list for this.

But the manufacturer of *your* software should ideally have a support page on this.

If you insist on a list, then there are the forums at MacRumors, especially [MacOS Mojave - App Compatibility](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-mojave-app-compatibility.2121547/)

and the almost comprehensive [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com/apps?platform=osx)